# Session asp.net info not changing

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm learning ASP.Net and I got into a problem I don't know how to resolve.

I got a page with some text boxes and some validators, and I want to do a post back to the page even if the validators.IsValid return false.

I want to do this because I want to give the user a option to login the site if he already in the user data base that I created and I want the loging register to be in the same page.
so I decided to use the Visible Property but the validator don't let me do post back if they are not valid.

this is the code of a test button I did after I got into trouble with my login page
this code doesn't work until I enter some character to the text box.

- I tried to use panels and update panels with ajax and nothing work.
- sorry for my English.

  ```
  UpdatePanel1.Visible = !UpdatePanel1.Visible;
  Panel1.Visible = !Panel1.Visible;
  ```

Comment: In your validators add EnableClientScript="false" to disable client side validation.

Comment: Ingenu, you should post that as an answer so samy can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your validators add EnableClientScript="false" to disable client side validation